# Jquery UI Dialogs (method?)

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery UI Dialogs

When click DELETE, a windows is opened and form appear.

On window there is an OK button. When clicked nothig happen.
Maybe I need to set method, but OK button is linked to below JS.

How to set up properly method?

Javascript OK Button:

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        OK: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

UI Dialog:

```
    <div class="widget">    
        <div class="head"><h5 class="iAlert">DELETE</h5></div>
        <div class="body aligncenter">
            <div class="uDialog">
                <div id="dialog-message" title="Delete">
                    <p><img src="images/exclamation.png" alt="" class="icon" /><br/>
                    <br/>
                    </p>
                    <div class="aligncenter">Input your password</div>
                    <div class="uiForm">
                        <form method="post" action="delete.php" class="mainForm">
                            <input type="password" value="" name="inputtext"/>
                        </form>                            
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Sample page content to illustrate the layering of the dialog -->
                <input type="button" value="DELETE" class="redBtn" id="opener" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working for you, since it's similar to the examples in the jQuery UI API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified OK function below where #delete is form ID.

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
    OK: function() {
    //$( this ).dialog( "close" );
            $("#delete").submit();

        }
    }
});
```